Why is the output impedance of an open-loop amplifier with a loading effect calculated by breaking the loop like this?
I'm a bit confused about how the author calculated the output impedance of the open-loop transconductance amplifier with the loading effect as follows.
(All images are taken from of the 6th edition of Microelectronic Circuits by Adel Sedra and Kenneth Smith, example 10.5 on page 838)
The full solution is a bit too long, and I'm not sure if it's okay to include it all here, so I’ve only included the relevant part.



Why is the output impedance calculated like this?
Why not \$ r_{o2}|| (R_L + R_F) \$

You are measuring impedance between D2 and D2', and connection between them was just disconnected, like said in the sentence you underlined.
You are NOT measuring impedance between the net "D2 and D2' connected" toward GND.
See below:
What you thought it was measured

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
What is actually measured:

simulate this circuit
Or equivalent:

simulate this circuit
Not all measurements are toward GND. Dont' worry, it is a very common misconception that you always measure to GND, especially if people had no chance to work with biased electronics, differential lines etc.
OF COURSE, you are NOT measuring the Voltage, i just didnt find the OHM meter symbol :)

Hi, I think you misunderstood my question a bit. I don't have any problem with the calculation, but I don't understand why they defined the output impedance that way.

But this is what i explained, it is calculated with an assumption that it's open between D2 points. So it will never be parallel. If the question is why, that's a whole other thing

At it is explainable in the following way: output voltage is pushed between nets D2 and D2'. So output impedance that is felt by the device is whatever is connected between this two points. And this is all 3 resistors luke shown above
